# install4j - Windows service terminates abnormally

Tags: install4j

install4j 5.x  window services now have 2 processes in task manager for each configured service.(ex> TEST.exe : 100MB, TEST.exe:1,500KB)

If you kill a process with a small memory out of the two, the Windows service will stop, but the process with large memory will not terminate.

When the Windows service is started in this state, there is a problem that several processes are running (only one of them needs to be executed).

This can cause problems when registering Windows Clustering.

I want to know how to terminate all 2 processes or to run as 1 process when Windows service is stopped.

Answer (score 0):

There are always two processes for service executables generated by install4j. The first one launches the actual JVM. This is required so that shutdown hooks are properly executed in your application. There is no option to change this behavior. You should never kill these processes but stop the associated service.